# Executing DB dump dynamically in codeception acceptance helper

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I want to execute different dump file for different codeception tests. Right now Db dump file is being executed from `shell_exec` command in `_before` method of `AcceptanceHelper`, that executes before each and every acceptance test. Something like suggested [here](http://phptest.club/t/codeception-tips-tricks/14/3). There are alot of tests in the app. So, the flow is as follows

```
- tests/acceptance/application/<contains alot of tests related to application>

- tests/acceptance/location/<contains alot of tests related to location>
```

Both test directories `/application/` and `/location/` uses same `AcceptanceHelper`. So, what i want is a different executable dump file for all of the tests inside `/application/` directory than that of `/location/` tests.

Think of something like [Get current running test name](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1251). Let's say `application_dump.sql` for all tests inside `/application/` directory and `location_dump.sql` for all tests inside `/location/` directory.

```
P.S: Using a different suite for application and location is ideally not what i am looking for.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help some one out there. As there was no proper way to achieve this as [Get current running test name](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1251) seems to be still in development.

So, this is how i managed to solve the issue. I have moved `shell_exec` commands out of `_before` method of `AcceptanceHelper` and created a new public method inside `AcceptanceHelper` which can be accessed via actor class `$I` in each and every acceptance test like so

```
$I->executeDbDump('application_dump.sql');
$I->executeDbDump('location_dump.sql');
```

Only drawback using this approach is i have to execute respective `executeDbDump` function before each and every test manually. But still seems to be best approach for the issue now.